# binary file bit manipuation

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

I have a binary file of image data where each pixel is **exactly 4 bits**. Image data is laid out as follow:

There a N images where the first image is 1x1, the second image is 2x2, the third is 4x4, and so on (they are mipmaps if you care to know).

Given a pointer to the start of the data buffer, I want to skip to the biggest image.

Now I know how many bytes I want to skip, but there is this annoying 1x1 image at the start which is 4 bits. I am not aware of anyway to increment a pointer by bit.

How can I successfully retrieve the data without everything being off by 4 bits?

Comment: That's why one normally uses padding, and so should you.

Comment: Store the smallest image as one byte (or four, if you're into performance), and you're done

Comment: If you have control over your image file format... just use [DDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface). Really, it's a good, cross-platform format for storing texture data. There's nothing Windows or Direct3D-specific about them. If you absolutely can't, then [use KTX](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/file_format_spec/), which has far less support, but it's just as comprehensive as DDS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can change your file format you can do either of the following:

- Add padding to the 1x1 image
- Store the images in reverse order (effectively the same as above, but not ideal for mip-maps because you don't necessarily know how many images you will have)

If you can't change your format, you have these choices:

- Convert the data
- Accept that the buffer is offset by half a byte and work with it accordingly

You said:

> How can I successfully retrieve the data without everything being off
>   by 4 bits?

So that means you need to convert.  When you calculate your offset in bytes, you will find that the first one contains half a byte of the previous image.  So in a pinch you can shuffle them like this:

```
for( i = start; i < end; i++ ) {
    p[i] = (p[i] << 4) | (p[i+1] >> 4);
}
```

That's assuming the first pixel is bits 4-7 and the second pixel is bits 0-3, and so on...  If it's the other way around, just invert those two shifts.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this assumes pixels points to bytes(unsigned chars)
index = ?;// your index to the pixel

byte_t b = pixels[index / 2];
if (index % 2) pixel = b >> 4;
else pixel = b & 15; 

// Or you can use
byte_t b = pixels[index >> 1];
if (index & 1) pixel = b >> 4;
else pixel = b & 15;
```

Either way just compute the logical index into the file. Dividing by two takes you to the start of the byte where the pixel is. And then just read the correct half of the byte.

So make a function

```
byte_t GetMyPixel(unsigned char* pixels, unsigned index) {
  byte_t b = pixels[index >> 1];
  byte_t pixel;
  if (index & 1) pixel = b >> 4;
  else pixel = b & 15; 
  return pixel; 
}
```

To read first image.

```
Image1x1 = GetMyPixel(pixels,0);



Image2x2_1 = GetMyPixel(pixels,1);// Top left pixel of second image
Image2x2_2 = GetMyPixel(pixels,2);// Top Right pixel of second image
Image2x2_3 = GetMyPixel(pixels,3);// Bottom left pixel of second image
... etc
```

So that is one way to go about it. You might need to take into account the endian-ness you are using so if it seems wrong then switch the logic for the pixel read thusly...

```
byte_t GetMyPixel(unsigned char* pixels, unsigned index) {
  byte_t b = pixels[index >> 1];
  byte_t pixel;
  #if OTHER_ENDIAN
  if (index & 1) pixel = b >> 4;
  else pixel = b & 15; 
  #else
  if (index & 1) pixel = b & 15;
  else pixel = b >> 4; 
  #endif
  return pixel; 
}
```